# error while installing sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to use sonata admin bundle for my project but while installing through this error:

```html
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.7 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.

 - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle ^2.3 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

please help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I recently updated a Symfony application to 2.8 and the only way to make SonataAdminBundle installable was to use `^2.3@dev` constraint in `composer.json`.